# Using ShouldBeEquivalentTo and handling different names

Tags: c#, nunit, fluent-assertions

I want to make a mapper test that maps a database model to a dto

In the database model there is

```
class Order
{
    long Id
}
```

But on the Dto the same field is named

```
class OrderDto
{
    long OrderId
}
```

Using ShouldBeEquivalentTo how do I tell FluentAssertions that these fields are the same, but the name is different?

Comment: I think, you couldn't and they are not the same, but you could map order to OrderDtpo and than compare.

Answer (score 1):

Its not exactly what you are asking for, but you can override the assertion comparison completely in fluent assertions for a given property with [Using When](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#equivalency-comparison-behavior). Its a little clunky and long winded syntax though if you need to do a lot of them. Probably the closest thing I can think of in there.

Comment: Had hoped for something better than Using, but could you maybe write an example, I cant figure out how it would look

Comment: hmmm, thinking back I think you may actually be better off excluding the problem fields and checking in addition to the original assertion. Its probably less code too tbh.

Comment: @Mech0z I'm afraid I haven't used that feature for quite a while. Thinking back, I think I did end up excluding the properties and comparing separately.

Answer (score 1):

This should finally be possible in [6.5 release](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/#comparing-members-with-different-names:):

```
orderDto.Should().BeEquivalentTo(order, options => options
    .WithMapping<OrderDto>(e => e.Id, s => s.OrderId));
```